# Catching the wrong exception

Tags: java, mysql, exception, error-handling

I am trying to catch a specific exception using `MySQL` in `Java`. However, it is running the `catch (SQLException ex)` instead of the one I want it to.

```
catch (MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException ex) {
}
catch (SQLException ex) {
}
```

Getting the following error, I would expect it to run the `catch (MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException ex)` function.

```
11:12:06 AM DAO.UserDAO createUser
SEVERE: null
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry 'idjaisjddiaij123ij' for key 'udid'
```

Why is it running `catch (SQLException ex)` instead of `catch (MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException ex)`?

Comment: Can you add ex.printStackTrace(); inside each catcha and paste the exception?

Comment: Does it appear in `.getCause()` by any chance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes `MySQL` always thow and catch the `SQLException` in the execution method. what you have to do is to catch the `SQLException` in your execution method, them throw new `MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException`

```
public void executeQuery() {
    try {
        // code
        rs = pstmt.executeQuery();
} catch (SQLException ex) {
   throw new MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException(ex);
}
```

so in the outer method that called the execute method, it should catch only the `MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException`

```
catch (MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException ex) {
   //handle ex
}
```

Comment: Even i have come across this situation and what Salah says is the way i did too. Somehow during execution you always end up getting SQLException , if u know what exception you are looking for then throwing it from within the catch block of SQLException is the right way to go.

Answer (score 6):

Make sure you use correct namespace. For me that one on image attached works like a charm.

[image: Correct namespace]

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to use `ex instanceof MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException` to make sure no other exception is thrown as a MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException since SQLException can be thrown for many different reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Please import

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException;
```

I tested and it will work.

Comment: How would the code compile in the first place without this class being imported?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and I had to show by a JOptionPane message the kind of error to the user.  This is my solution

```
public boolean executeQuery() {
try {
        // code
        rs = pstmt.executeQuery();
} catch (SQLException ex) {
   int errCode = ex.getErrorCode();
     if(errCode == 1062){ //MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException 
     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Duplicate entry for id.\n");}
     return false;
}
```