# creating System.out.println for MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry for key 'PRIMARY'

Tags: java, mysql

I have a chunk of code where a user can select a student ID and a class ID and enroll that student in the class.  I'm am trying to have it, so there is an error message if the student tries to enroll in a course they are already in.  I get the CVE error saying duplicate entry, which is what I want, but how can I print out this error to the user? I tried a catch with the CVE error, but must be getting something wrong.

```
public static void addClass() {

    try {
        rs = myStmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM ClassSelector.classes");
        while (rs.next()) {
            String availableClasses = rs.getString("class_id") + "\t" + rs.getString("class_name") + "\t" + rs.getString("description");
            System.out.println(availableClasses);
        }
        System.out.println("Enter Class ID from Classes Listed Above to Join: ");
        selectedClass = sc.nextLine();
        rs = myStmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM ClassSelector.classes WHERE class_id = " + selectedClass);
        while (rs.next()) {
            String innerJoin = (userEnterIdAsName + " has been added to " + rs.getString("class_name") + " " + rs.getString("class_id"));
            System.out.println(innerJoin);
            String student_x_classJoin = "INSERT INTO student_x_class" + "(student_id, student_name, class_id, class_name)" + "VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)";
            PreparedStatement pStmt = con.prepareStatement(student_x_classJoin);
                pStmt.setString(1, user_entered_student_id);
                pStmt.setString(2, userEnterIdAsName);
                pStmt.setString(3, rs.getString("class_id"));
                pStmt.setString(4, rs.getString("class_name"));
                pStmt.executeUpdate();
                System.out.println("Would you like to enroll " + userEnterIdAsName + " into another class? (Y/N)");
                String addAdditionalClass = sc.nextLine();
                if (addAdditionalClass.equalsIgnoreCase("Y")) {
                    addClass();
                } else if (addAdditionalClass.equalsIgnoreCase("N")) {
                    return;
                }
            }
    }
    catch (java.sql.SQLException SQL) {
        SQL.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The Error comes from this line:

String student_x_classJoin

Thanks

this is the error:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry '33-315' for key 'PRIMARY'
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:404)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:387)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:932)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3878)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3814)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2478)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2625)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2551)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1861)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2073)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2009)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeLargeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:5094)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:1994)
    at ClassSelectorApp.addClass(ClassSelectorApp.java:168)
    at ClassSelectorApp.signUp(ClassSelectorApp.java:122)
    at ClassSelectorApp.main(ClassSelectorApp.java:29)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
```

Comment: Yes, the problem is at line 423, says my crystal ball. Post your code if you don't trust crystal balls. That said, why don't you check before inserting?

Comment: OK, so where is the catch block that catches the exception and displays the error message to the user?

Comment: thats what I couldn't figure out.  I tried adding catch (MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
before the other catch, but it didn't recognize MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException...

Comment: Maybe MySQL is not throwing that exception http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21904707/catching-the-wrong-exception

Comment: Copy the message that you are obtaining from the printStackTrace and maybe we can point out wich exceptcion you should catch

Comment: I added the error message

Answer (score 0):

You can use another try-catch surronding your sentence

```
     pStmt.executeUpdate();
```

like the one explained in [Catching the wrong exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21904707/catching-the-wrong-exception)

EDITED after stack trace

```
    try {
        pstmt.executeUpdate();
    } catch (MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException ex) {
          System.out.println("Duplicated entry"); // or whatever message you want
          throw new SQLException("Duplicated entry"); // "jump" to external catch
    }
```

Comment: hi, thanks for the help, but this doesn't seem to work

Comment: I have changed my answer after reading your update. I can not undestand why the exception generated by MySQL is not catched. It should be catched in your original catch (it extends from SQLException http://www.docjar.com/docs/api/com/mysql/jdbc/exceptions/MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException.html ) or in my proposed catch.